# Disappearing label inside TextView When textViewDidStartEditing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

Because it is not a default function in UITextViews I want to add an PlaceHolder text inside the textview, through adding a label to it and when i start typing the [label.hidden=Yes]
the textview is placed inside a UICollectionViewCell that is populated and brought up when I use a UIImagePickerControl to pick an image from my photo library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UITextView` delegate functions to achieve the hide/unhide effect somewhat similar to `UITextField` effect, just set text in your textview to your placeholder text, for example "Placeholder Text"

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@"Placeholder Text"]) {
        [textView setText:@""];
        [textView setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (![textView.text length]) {
        [textView setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:185/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        [textView setText:@"Placeholder Text"];
    }
}
```

Comment: this will give me a placeholder yes, but because my textView is in a collectionViewCell that is populated by a UIImagePickerControl , if I add text to textview and Add another image to the collection the text shifts to another textView.

Comment: this has to be managed inside the code to display the collectionviewcells which is a different thing and can be checked only at your end